# Class 'JasonGuru\LaravelMakeRepository\Repository\BaseRepository' not found

Tags: laravel

I got the following problem in Laravel:

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException thrown with message "Class 'JasonGuru\LaravelMakeRepository\Repository\BaseRepository' not found"

Stacktrace:
#0 Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException in .../app/Repositories/Back/News/NewsRepository.php:19
```

NewsRepository.php

```
16. /**
17.  * Class NewsRepository.
18.  */
19. class NewsRepository extends BaseRepository
20. {
```

Does someone have any idea about this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
composer require jason-guru/laravel-make-repository --dev
```

Comment: That is not possible in production environment and when you try to install composer with --no-dev flag it causes problem to your application.

Answer (score 0):

rebuild your autoload file by `composer dumpautoload`